# Collapse all steps in Angular Material vertical Stepper

Tags: angular-material, mat-stepper

I want to implement a vertical stepper in my application, but can't find any way to start with an "all collapsed" state. The goal is that the user can see the whole collapsed step list on the screen before clicking a step and starting to fill or edit data. Is this possible in any way, or is there a workaround I could use to achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like you described Materials' expansion panel

Comment: Not quite, as the steps sre numbered and should be opened sequentially. I can obviously customize an expansion panel implementation, but the stepper seemed like a better option.